# gulp-sass @import CSS file

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, gulp-sass

Using gulp-sass I can include .scss files with `@import 'filepath.scss';`

But when I try to import normal css files with `@import 'filepath.css'`, It just added the import line of `import url(filepath.css);` to the output css file, rather than actually importing the code.

How can I import CSS files as well as SCSS files? I want to do this to include files form bower.

Here is my gulp function:

```
// include gulp
var gulp = require('gulp');

// include deps
var minifyCSS  = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    autoprefix = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    rename     = require('gulp-rename'),
    sass       = require('gulp-sass');

var targets = {
    css: './output/css'
};

// compile CSS
gulp.task('sass', function() {

    gulp.src([
        './app/assets/scss/app.scss', 
        './app/assets/scss/app-admin.scss'
    ])
    .pipe(sass({
        includePaths: [
            './bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/stylesheets', 
            './bower_components'
        ],
        errLogToConsole: true
    }))

    .pipe(autoprefix('last 2 versions'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(targets.css))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(rename(function (path) { path.basename += '.min'; }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(targets.css));
});
```

For instance I want to include datatables which is at `datatables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css` relative to the bower directory as included above.

So in my `app.scss` file I have `@import 'datatables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css';`

If I can't use gulp-sass to do this, how else could I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Passing some parameters to minifyCSS allows me to achieve this.

```
.pipe(minifyCSS({
        relativeTo: './bower_components',
        processImport: true
    }))
```

**Sources:**
[gulp-minify-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-css) depends on [clean-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clean-css), referenced options explained [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clean-css#how-to-use-clean-css-programmatically).

Comment: The [gulp-minify-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-css) package has now been deprecated.  This was a big problem for me, because the suggested replacement (gulp-cssnano) does not include a similar feature.

What I ended up doing was using PostCSS and running autoprefixer and postcss-import using that package, and then running gulp-cssnano once those two were complete.  The result is the same, and you aren't using a deprecated package.  @Ezra FYI

Comment: @evanhuntley gulp-clean-css supports processImport but now I think the option is just called "inline" and defaults to "inline:['local']" so will automatically import the css code

Answer (score 7):

[gulp-cssimport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cssimport) is a good choice if you also want css imports to work in non-minified development environments.

Answer (score 1):

i just rename my "filename.css" to "filename.scss" and 
    @import "filename";
without file extension.

Answer (score 0):

Quite often this is solved simply by listing all the files in the HTML file like so:

```
<!-- 'vendor' styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="datatables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="some/other/plugin.css"/>
<!-- refernce to the SCSS compilation output -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css"/>
```

I suppose this will have the downside of not being able to refernce to the classes defined in the 'vendor' CSS files from the SCSS files for example with `@extend` directive (I haven't had the need to do so). Other than that, I don't think there's any functional reason why it could not be done this way since it is not possible to define variables, mixins or other reusable blocks of style in the css files.

However, many want to combine the CSS files into one css file because of two reasons:

1. Minimizing the amount of files needed to load (=the amount of HTTP requests) will speed up the page loading time
2. Using a css opitmiser (such as [csso](https://github.com/ben-eb/gulp-csso)) can find overlaps from the one monolithic CSS file and this the omptimization might be more efficient.

To achieve this, [gulp-useref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-useref) is often used. To do so, the HTML needs to have special coments surrounding the stylesheets references:

```
<!-- build:css styles/combined.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="datatables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="some/other/plugin.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css"/>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

The magic comments above instruct useref to concatenate the CSS files referenced between the comments to a file named `styles/combined.css`. Of course, for this to happen, you'll need to instruct the usage of useref in your gulpfile, something like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    useref = require('gulp-useref'),
    gulpif = require('gulp-if'),
    csso = require('gulp-csso');

gulp.task('html', function () {
    var assets = useref.assets();

    return gulp.src('app/*.html')
        .pipe(assets)
        .pipe(gulpif('*.css', csso()))
        .pipe(assets.restore())
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Note that the SCSS files need to be compiled first for this to work.

One of the reasons of doing it this way is that the processing time required to get a viewable HTML page with working CSS when developing is minimized. That is, after you've made modifications to your SCSS files, the only thing that gulp needs to do to be able to display the changes is to compile the SCSS files, as the CSS references between the 'magical comments' will work as such. If you use [browserSync](http://www.browsersync.io/) to view the changes after save, this will help minimize the lag for the changes to be displayed in your browser(s). Only 'compiling for production' you need to use 'gulp-useref'.

I recommend taking a look at some of the [Slush](http://slushjs.github.io/) or [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) generators, or rather the code they generate. At least the Yeoman generator '[gulp-webapp](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-gulp-webapp)' seems to use useref. Even if you don't want to use the generators, their output serves as a good recipe book for discovering best practices (assuming the generator in question is well made).

Answer (score 0):

I know this question already has an accepted answer but, for anyone who might come across this, I would suggest using [gulp-importer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-importer). This plugin is highly configurable and applies imports, not only for CSS files but for any kind of files.

Alongside other options, the plugin allows customizing the regex pattern used in placing the import statements. So, there are no worries that the syntax might break.

Give it a try! :)