# SCSS: how to actually include the contents of a @include?

Tags: css, import, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm moving from Grunt to Gulp and noticed that [gulp-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass) does not include the contents of files referenced by `@import "reset.css"` statements. Instead, it normalizes the url reference, as `@import url(reset.css)`. My intention is to have a single CSS reference on my `index.html`, that would be the concatenation of my CSS dependencies.

It's a simple *read-file-and-output-contents* operation, but I bet this is already implemented and I just don't know where to find it -- I'm still new on this ecosystem and would not like to spend time *reinventing the wheel*.

**EDIT:** the selected answer for this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27727803/gulp-sass-import-css-file) uses `gulp-minify-css`, instead of `gulp-sass`. Exchanging them could be a short-term solution, but I'd prefer to avoid my new build system to rely on unstable plugins. Moreover, I actually have plans to use `scss`, so I'd be back to having to deal with `gulp-sass` again. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0):

`@import` should actually include the contents of the file, not make a reference to it. Sounds like maybe the transpiling of the SCSS to CSS isn't working properly.